# Connect Excel to Access - VBA

Tags: vba, ado

I get a "User-defined type not defined" error when I execute the below code,  and the

> "objCon As ADODB.Connection"

is highlighted on the first line.
I am trying  to set a connection from Excel to Access via VBA code. Thank you for any advice!

```
Private objCon As ADODB.Connection
Private rstRec As ADODB.Recordset
Private strQry

Sub Connect()
   Dim strConn As String


   Set objCon = New ADODB.Connection
   objCon.Mode = adModeReadWrite

      If objCon.State = adStateClosed Then
         strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & "C:\DB\Db.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
         objCon.ConnectionString = strConn
         objCon.Open
      End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, have you add ActiveX  inside Tools->reference?  
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819

Comment: Oh my, that was it, it worked! Fabulous. Please add as an answer so I can add points for you.

Comment: I suggest closing the question, this question has been asked many time before, you can search for VBA ADODB REFERENCE on SO or Google to find the solution. :)

Comment: Cqn I close, and if so, how? Or maybe only a mod can do it?

Comment: can you see `share|edit|close|delete|flag` above the comments? the `delete` 
If not I can make it as an answer..

Comment: Depending in what you want to do, it is often better to use DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet to link a sheet or range as a table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do one of the following

```
set objCon  = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
set rstRec = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
```

Or in VBA Editor
Tools-->Reference--> 
Add `Microsoft ActiveX Data Object X.Y Library`